# Simplifications of sum of matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have a series matrices and would like to compute the sum for each $n$. For real and square matrices $A$ and $B$, the series is given as
$$S(n)=A+BAB^\top+B^2A(B^\top)^2+\cdots+B^nA(B^\top)^n.$$
I know that the power of $B$ can be easily computed by eigendecomposition, but I do not know if this can be simplified further. Or if there are any tricks for computing $S(n)$ in `R`. I appreciate any help!

Comment: If B is not square who do you define $B^n$?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, B is a square matrix and I have edited my post.

Comment: What's the context of where this sum came from? Might help us find an answer

Comment: You could argue that $S(\infty)=A+B S(\infty)B^\top$, and that $S(n)=S(\infty)-B^{n+1}S(\infty)(B^\top)^{n+1}$.  I'm not sure how to solve $S(\infty)$.

Comment: We encounter this sum from a construction of a Gaussian process, and it is a part of the covariane matrix. Here $n$ is the number of samples. We want to simplify this so that we can calculate the rate of convergence to its stationary distribution.